# How to get the solution name in vsix project templates?

Tags: vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm creating a VS template through vsix. I can get the project name using $safeprojectname$ parameter of replacementdictionary. Like the way, is it possible to get the solution name? I can get the solution name in add-in using dte object. But how to do it in templates?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use $SpecificSolutionName$, I think.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

Comment: It seems it is available in VS2013 and above only. Not available in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Use $specifiedsolutionname$ (lower case). this is the name of the Solution.